# ruby multiline statement returns different value than inline statement

Tags: ruby

I have introduced a bug into my sourcecode by simply separating join/map/split statements. I can't understand why this behavior happens. Any idea why this happens and how to get `func2` to act as `func1`?

```rb
def func1(params)
  params.split('&').map { |str| str.split('=').last }.join('-')
end

def func2(params)
  params.split('&')
        .map { |str| str.split('=').last }
        .join('-')
end

func1("a=1&b=2&c=3") # "1-2-3"
func2("a=1&b=2&c=3") # ["a=1", "b=2", "c=3"]
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. On my machine, both methods return the same: `"1-2-3"` Btw it looks like you are trying to parse a query parameter string, did you consider using `CGI.parse`?

Comment: I am getting `"1-2-3"` also. maybe it's a version difference. what version ruby are you using?

Comment: @spickermann I found this bug while refactoring to CGI.parse actually.
@HenokTeklu `ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin19]`

Comment: Did you use Pry as Ruby console, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I can reproduce with Ruby 2.6.3 and [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki) 0.12.2:

```
[1] pry(main)> def func1(params)
[1] pry(main)*   params.split('&').map { |str| str.split('=').last }.join('-')  
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> :func1
[2] pry(main)> 
[3] pry(main)> def func2(params)
[3] pry(main)*   params.split('&')  
[3] pry(main)*   .map { |str| str.split('=').last }        
sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Error: there was a problem executing system command: map { |str| str.split('=').last }
[3] pry(main)*   .join('-')        
sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Error: there was a problem executing system command: join('-')
[3] pry(main)* end  
=> :func2
[4] pry(main)> 
[5] pry(main)> func1("a=1&b=2&c=3") # "1-2-3"
=> "1-2-3"
[6] pry(main)> func2("a=1&b=2&c=3") # ["a=1", "b=2", "c=3"]
=> ["a=1", "b=2", "c=3"]
[7] pry(main)> Pry::VERSION
=> "0.12.2"
```

It seems to work fine with standard IRB:

```
2.6.3 :001 > def func1(params)
2.6.3 :002?>     params.split('&').map { |str| str.split('=').last }.join('-')
2.6.3 :003?>   end
 => :func1 
2.6.3 :004 > 
2.6.3 :005 > def func2(params)
2.6.3 :006?>     params.split('&')
2.6.3 :007?>           .map { |str| str.split('=').last }
2.6.3 :008?>           .join('-')
2.6.3 :009?>   end
 => :func2 
2.6.3 :010 > 
2.6.3 :011 > func1("a=1&b=2&c=3") # "1-2-3"
 => "1-2-3" 
2.6.3 :012 > func2("a=1&b=2&c=3") # ["a=1", "b=2", "c=3"]
 => "1-2-3"
```

Changing to

```
def func2(params)
  params.split('&').map do |str|
    str.split('=').last
  end.join('-')
end
```

solves the problem in Pry.

This [issue](http://Need%20easy%20way%20to%20paste%20multiline%20code) ("Need easy way to paste multiline code") might be related.

Comment: I was trying it on the rails console, but the bug came from our production Sinatra server running on puma in an EC2 Linux Machine